# Does std::function() check the type when compiling code in C++11 in VS2010?

Tags: c++, c++11, typechecking, std-function

I am using `std::function()` in my code with C++11 and VS2010. Here is my code.

```
function<string (string)> myfunc = 3;
myfunc(string());
```

It is obvious that the code is incorrect ,for the `myfunc` object is not initialized properly. The `myfunc` object should be valued by the `function<string (string)>` object other than the integer type. And when running to the code `myfunc(string());`, `std::function` object throws the `bad_function_call()` and gets error.

However,what confused me is why C++11 do not check the type during the compiling time? It is so strange because lack of type check will make programmers easily mess up the code incidentally, until running to the according error line.

So I want to ask: Does `std::function()` check the type when compiling code in C++11 in VS2010? If not,is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: It is valid, you have a pointer to a function which takes and returns a string, and you are passing it a string. However it is a nullptr so it will throw at runtime.

Comment: This has to be a bug. The first line should not compile

Comment: @paulm: No that assignment is not correct, it shouldn't even compile (with GCC 4.7: `error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘std::function<...>’ requested`).

Comment: my bad, I didn't even notice he was assigning 3 to it :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a hack in MS's implementation of `std::function` to allow for the following:

```
function<string (string)> myfunc = NULL;
```

This is the piece of code I could find in MS's implementation of the `<functional>` header:

```
#if defined(_NATIVE_NULLPTR_SUPPORTED) \
    && !defined(_DO_NOT_USE_NULLPTR_IN_STL)
    function(int)
    {   // construct empty function wrapper from null pointer
        this->_Reset();
    }
#endif /* defined(_NATIVE_NULLPTR_SUPPORTED) etc. */
```

So it looks like this constructor is enabled conditionally based on the level of standard conformance the user wants.

However, there is no such a constructor in the C++11 Standard Library specification (see paragraph 20.8.11.2.1).

Comment: Thank you for replying. Is there any method to prevent this situation,or check the function type when compiling code in case the programmers initialize the wrong type?